# I'm Trying To Update Three Columns Containing Arrays in PostgreSQL Where They Will All Simultaneously Be Updated By Index Using ARRAY_REMOVE

Tags: arrays, postgresql

So Far I Have This:

The Table Structures Are As Follows:

> meals: [mid, dish, is_entree, Array(ingredients_ids), Array(ingredients_uids), Array(ingredients_numbers), meal, details, uid]

> ingredients: [iid, ingredient , measurement, price, uid]

What I'm doing is Adding the iid i.e ingredient_id, along with the number needed for said dish, along with the user who created the ingredient, all associated information thus stated is in the same index within each array

What i'm trying to achieve is once an ingredient is removed then this function will be called in JavaScript to remove the associated data in the meals table where there is a match.
I'm just using Beekeeper right now for testing as it helps with syntax etc. And then I'll convert it to a string format later.

So I should be able to remove them by index and have all items updated together using the same index...I think

It Works On Items Where There is Only One Such Ingredient That Matches But Not If The Dish Contains  More Than One Ingredient

The RETURNING Statement was placed there just for checking the results instead of commenting the code out and doing a

```
SELECT * FROM meals
```

every time.

Since ARRAY_REMOVE requires a value instead of an index I create the value with the ARRAY_POSITION function instead since I'm Working with indices to do a one size fits all approach.

Also, There Are No Errors In This code.

Thanks In Advance.

The PostgreSQL code I have so far is:

```
with missing_ids AS (
 SELECT ingredient_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
    UNNEST(ingredients_ids) ingredient_id
    FROM meals
  ) AS separated_ingredients
  WHERE ingredient_id NOT IN (SELECT iid FROM ingredients)
  GROUP BY ingredient_id
),


missing_iid_and_index_of_iid AS (
  SELECT mid, ingredient_id, ARRAY_POSITION(ingredients_ids, missing_ids.ingredient_id) as missing_index
  FROM meals
  JOIN missing_ids ON missing_ids.ingredient_id = ANY(ingredients_ids)
  ORDER BY mid  
)


UPDATE meals
SET
ingredients_ids = ARRAY_REMOVE(meals.ingredients_ids, ARRAY_POSITION(meals.ingredients_ids, missing.missing_index)),
ingredients_uids = ARRAY_REMOVE(meals.ingredients_uids, ARRAY_POSITION(meals.ingredients_uids, missing.missing_index)),
ingredients_numbers = ARRAY_REMOVE(meals.ingredients_numbers, ARRAY_POSITION(meals.ingredients_numbers, missing.missing_index))
FROM missing_iid_and_index_of_iid as missing
WHERE missing.mid = meals.mid AND missing.ingredient_id = ANY(meals.ingredients_ids)

RETURNING ingredients_ids, missing.ingredient_id, missing.missing_index, ingredients_uids, ingredients_numbers, missing.mid, meals.mid
```

Comment: This doesn't directly address the question; however, it's an important design consideration. Using arrays of IDs that reference another table is almost certainly a poor design decision because it precludes using the database's ability to enforce referential integrity. A better model would be to have an associative table (with `incgredient_number` as an attribute) that links meals to ingredients. Doing so makes it practical to maintain referential integrity and greatly simplifies the logic for adding and removing ingredients from a meal.

Comment: Despite the statement, "There Are No Errors In This code," the fact is that there are several errors. If there were no errors, then there wouldn't be a need to post a question. The code doesn't perform as desired, so it is defective somewhere. One repeated error is the misuse of `ARRAY_REMOVE` to attempt to remove array elements by position when `ARRAY_REMOVE` instead removes all elements of the array that are not distinct from the second argument.

Comment: `ARRAY_POSITION` returns the index of the first element in the array with the given value, not the value; therefore, it doesn't fix the problem mentioned in my prior comment (you probably intended to use the position to index into the array; e.g., `ingredients_ids[ARRAY_POSITION(...)]`). Removing array elements by value is logically flawed. If the same user created more than one ingredient used in a meal, but not all of those ingredients are missing, then removing elements from `ingredients_uids` based that user's ID will remove too many elements.

Comment: I could be mistaken but I believe this is solved by making the ingredient Id the source of the index.

Comment: Also by no error, I mean there are not syntax errors though obviously there are bugs i.e unwanted or undesired results.

Comment: And yes it does seem if it removed all the fitting values added into the ARRAY_REMOVE function then yes I did not have the proper understanding of that code. Also for each ingredient, there is a UNIQUE constraint so if that helps

Comment: John I have verified and the second argument in ARRAY_REMOVE does in fact determine the value to be removed. It will remove all instances of that value from the array. Not all that don't match the value provided. But if you could offer me some insight as to how I might compile the arrays of iids and uids with the array of numbers for each ingredient. That Is added separately from the application as a user defined option with a default of 1 and has no entry within the ingredients table itself. This of course would be very bad form and perhaps is what you were referring to earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, using arrays of IDs referencing other tables is a poor design choice since it precludes referential integrity constraints on those IDs. There are several other issues:

1. Positionally linked arrays are often problematic.
2. Searches of large arrays for specific values is inefficient.
3. The data is denormalized (the contents of `ingredients_uids` is fully dependent on `ingredients_ids`) which can result in inconsistent data.
4. Unnesting and aggregating arrays adds unnecessary complexity to the logic.

Given the design choices presented in the original post, the following query achieves the desired results:

```
UPDATE meals
  SET ingredients_ids = new_values.ingredients_ids,
      ingredients_uids = new_values.ingredients_uids,
      ingredients_numbers = new_values.ingredients_numbers
  FROM (SELECT meals.mid,
               ARRAY_AGG(mi.iid ORDER BY mi.n) AS ingredients_ids,
               ARRAY_AGG(mi.uid ORDER BY mi.n) AS ingredients_uids,
               ARRAY_AGG(mi.ingredients_number ORDER BY mi.n) AS ingredients_numbers
          FROM meals
          CROSS JOIN unnest(meals.ingredients_ids, meals.ingredients_uids, meals.ingredients_numbers) WITH ORDINALITY mi(iid, UID, ingredients_number, n)
          JOIN ingredients
            ON mi.iid = ingredients.iid
          GROUP BY meals.mid) new_values
  WHERE meals.mid = new_values.mid
    AND CARDINALITY(meals.ingredients_ids) <> CARDINALITY(new_values.ingredients_ids)
  RETURNING meals.*;
```

As in the original post, the results of the update are returned to facilitate checking the results.

Comment: So JohnH. If I wanted to make the day normalized what would you recommend I do, what other tables other than number might be necessary and how would I solve the conflict of needing an undetermined number of ingredients for each dish using SQL reasonably. The database was previously implemented using MongoDB but I needed to port it over to sql. You seem much more knowledgeable in creating a database schema so I'm happy to take your suggestions here. Tomorrow however, I will try implementing your solution and see if it works as a temporary solution. And again thanks for all your advice.

Comment: The code given does indeed produce the correct results. Thank you John.